# Reading Facebook page wall with cron

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to integrate a facebook page wall into my website application.  I have no problem with doing so when user is logged in with hes facebook account and is accessing the page wall within my app.  What i want to do is to make possible to retrieve those posts with cron job and notify user if new posts are up by mail.  When i try to do that i am getting access token error.  I have red about offline_access permission but its being deprecated and i couldn't find what the new solution is.
Is it possible to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ + https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `offline_access`, you need to get a long-lived access token. The process and scenarios are described on the [Facebook Developers Site](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/). Note that you will only be able to read the user's wall for a limited time only before you have to ask the user to login again. You will also need the `read_stream` permission.